# find if child element exist by variable

Tags: xslt

I have long list from a query statement to check if the said tag exist. If it does. copy-of with value. If not do something else with it.
  I am trying to do something like

```
 <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$TEST1/THING/row/name() = $tagname">
        <xsl:copy-of select = "$TEST1/THING/row/name()"/>
        </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
    <!-- DO something -->
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

And it is not working! Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide the input XML, whole XSLT, and expected output..

Comment: Moreover, copy-of has name() in its select.. it will copy the name of the element(in this case 'row') as text and not the value of the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:when test="$TEST1/THING/row/*[name() = $tagname]">
```

Note that this is pretty much a guess. Without context, that's all you can get.

Comment: That is it. Thank you!! What happens if I need to add multiple condition. name = $this or name = $that. I tried the $TEST1/THING/row/*[name() = $tagname or name() = $tagname2] doesn't seem to work for the syntax?